# Using a sub-query to list greater than averages

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

What I have is a table which has the prices of book titles. What I'm trying to do is to list the book titles that have a greater than average price. What I have so far is :

```
SELECT TITLES.PRICE, AVG(TITLES.PRICE) AS "KOMPARE"
FROM TITLES,
            (SELECT PRICE, AVG(PRICE)
            FROM TITLES
            GROUP BY Price) subquery1

WHERE TITLES.PRICE = subquery1.PRICE
AND subquery1.PRICE > TITLES.KOMPARE
GROUP BY TITLES.PRICE;
```

The error that I am getting is that `TITLES.KOMPARE` is a invalid identifier. I'm not sure why as I defined it in the first select statement. And it's not like I could put `AVG(TITLES.PRICE)` in the `AND` statement. I would be forever thankful for anyone who can offer me some advice! Thank you.

FYI my table name is TITLES, and the prices of the books are PRICE.

Comment: 50 minutes is nothing, especially if you are new.

Comment: Use `HAVING` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

for aggregation function you should use having and no alias

```
SELECT TITLES.PRICE, AVG(TITLES.PRICE) AS "KOMPARE"
FROM TITLES,
        (SELECT PRICE, AVG(PRICE)
        FROM TITLES
        GROUP BY Price) subquery1
WHERE TITLES.PRICE = subquery1.PRICE
GROUP BY TITLES.PRICE
HAVING TITLES.PRICE > AVG(TITLES.PRICE)
```

could be you are looking for  somethings like

```
select  TITLES.PRICE,select AVG(TITLES.PRICE) from TITLES   )
from TITLES   
where TITLES.PRIVE  > (select AVG(TITLES.PRICE) from TITLES   );
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying not a GROUP BY Expression

Comment: Update the answer but you query have no sense ..

Comment: I have update the answe with a my suggestion

Comment: Still **ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
Error at Line: 4 Column: 8**. See for yourself: `WITH
Titles (BOOKNAME, price) AS (
  SELECT 1, 2.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 5.00 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TITLES.BOOKNAME, AVG(TITLES.PRICE) AS "KOMPARE"
FROM TITLES
GROUP BY TITLES.BOOKNAME
HAVING TITLES.PRICE > AVG(TITLES.PRICE);`

Answer (score 0):

Your query makes no sense, getting the average PRICE while grouping by PRICE?

```
SELECT TITLE.*
FROM TITLES
CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT AVG(PRICE) AS avgPrice
    FROM TITLES
  ) subquery1
WHERE TITLES.PRICE > avgPrice
;
```

Or better:

```
SELECT *
FROM TITLES
WHERE TITLES.PRICE >
  (
    SELECT AVG(PRICE) AS avgPrice
    FROM TITLES
  )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work along:

```
SELECT
  price
  , ROUND((SELECT AVG(price) FROM Titles), 2) AS kompare
FROM Titles
WHERE price > (SELECT AVG(price) FROM Titles)
;
```

You might want to retrieve more columns from **Titles** - which was not possible the way, you wrote your statement. (But why would you `GROUP BY` price in the first place?)

You could even have the difference listed:

```
SELECT
  Titles.*
  , ROUND(price - (SELECT AVG(price) FROM Titles), 2) AS difference
FROM Titles
WHERE price > (SELECT AVG(price) FROM Titles)
;
```

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.